# Link extraction from website

Tags: python, data-extraction

I am trying to extract some data from WebMD and once I run my code I keep geeting a "None" as a return. Any idea what I am doing wrong. I have the number of returns the same as the number of links but I do not get the links.

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request
import pandas as pd


source = urllib.request.urlopen('https://messageboards.webmd.com/').read()

soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')

for url in soup.find_all('div',class_="link"):
    print (url.get('href'))
```

Comment: `print (url.get('href'))` return you `None` ?

Comment: yes. not just this line but the whole code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `url` element is actually a `div` tag, not an `a`:

```
>>> x = soup.find_all('div', class_="link")
>>> x[0]
<div class="link"><a href="https://messageboards.webmd.com/family-pregnancy/f/relationships/">Relationships</a></div>
```

You need to select the child before getting the href attribute:

```
>>> x[0].a.get('href')
'https://messageboards.webmd.com/family-pregnancy/f/relationships/'
```

Just modify your for loop as follows:

```
for url in soup.find_all('div',class_="link"):
    print (url.a.get('href'))
```

Answer (score 0):

`soup.find_all('div',class_="link")` returns all `div` elements with the class `link`. These elements wrap the `a` elements that contain the href attributes, so you need to get the href from the correct element like so:

```
for div in soup.find_all('div',class_="link"):
    print (div.a.get('href'))
```